# Finding edges represented as lists

Tags: python, list

Suppose we have a bipartite graph in which the nodes are represented as list. For example suppose a bipartite graph has the nodes as `l1 = [1,2,3,4,5]` and `l2 = [6,7,8,9,10]` are the nodes in the two partitions The edges are [[1,8, 'a'], [4,9,'b']] represented as list of list as given in the figure [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OTjf3.png)

[image: figure 2]

If somehow we have merged the nodes of the bipartite graph and this is now represented as in [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OTjf3.png) by `[[1,2,3], [4, 5]]` and `[[6,7] , [8, 9, 10]]` then in this new graph, we would have edges between these groups if there is an edge between any pair in the original graph. For example, in the above, there would be an `a` edge between groups `[1,2,3]` and `[8,9,10]` since there is an edge originally between 1 and 8, this is depicted in Figure [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OTjf3.png). How do find the edges in the new graph in Python, what would be a suitable data structure representation and how to find the resulting edges from this original graph?

[image: figure 1]

I have used lists for this, but the problem is to find these edges, I am having to iterate over all the nodes in the new graph to check if there should be an edge. Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Code I have tried :

```
l1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
l2 = [6,7,8,9,10]
l3 = [[1,2,3], [4, 5]]
l4 = [[6,7] , [8, 9, 10]]
edges = [[1,8, 'a'], [4,9,'b']]

for e in edges:
    for l in l3:
        for k in l4:
            if e[0] in l and e[1] in k:
                print(e[0], e[1], e[2])
```

Comment: What edges do you wanna find? Could you give an example of an expected output? You could also paste the images directly. There is no need for an external link

Comment: What would the output look like? How do you handle the situation if two edges are squeezed together when you collapse partition cells to single nodes? Does the resulting structure have two edges or just one? If the latter, how is the resulting edge labeled (since your structure seems to be one of edge-labeled graphs). A problem with your representation is that there is no good way to tell when node `i` is connected with node `j`. Your representation forces numerous linear scans over the data structure. A dictionary-based approach would be superior, e.g. `{(1,8):'a', (4,9):'b'}`

Comment: @UliSotschok OP doesn't have the rep to paste images.

Comment: @UliSotschok The edges would be the edges between the groups. as depicted in Figure 2

Comment: @JohnColeman I have updated the question to reflect that. If two edges are squeezed together, we would take the maximum lexicographic value, but just one edge. How would the dictionary based representation work, that is indeed my question.

Comment: What have you done to solve this problem yourself? Have you don't any research that you'd care to share with us? Stack Overflow is not a free coding service after all.

Comment: @MadPhysicist I have used lists for this, but the problem is to find these edges, I am having to iterate over all the nodes in the new graph to check if there should be an egde. Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: @ephemeral. Possibly, but I can't say for sure without seeing what you did. Please edit it into your question.

Comment: Where is the code you did to try to solve it?

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh I have added the code

Comment: @MadPhysicist I have added the code that I have tried

Comment: if you want to find valid edge in bipartite graph, l1 and l2 is enough. I don't understand the effect of l3 and l4 here. please clarify your problem, then we can help you.

Comment: l3 and l4 is the grouping that has been formed, let us assume according to some grouping algorithm @recnac

Comment: so your requirement is find the edges which one node in l3 and another in l4? I think set will be more suitable here. O(1) to find

Comment: @recnac yes edges with one node in l3 and another one in l4 if there is an edge between  l1 and l2 for any pair of nodes in the sub list we are considering

Comment: so we can just combine all the sub list of l3 and l4 into one list, because it doesn't matter? if it is true, the combination result will be l1 and l2. so it is what confuse me.

Comment: @recnac no they cant be combined, the diagrams I think illustrate this better

Comment: @recnac Uli's answer is the solution. Question is, is this the best performance wise?

Comment: @ephemeral like I said, if you want to speed up, you can change the data structure to set, which impove time complexity from O(n) to O(1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's start by getting the index of the group that contains the specific value.

```py
def idx_group_in_list(value, list_) -> int:
    """e.g. value=2, list_=[[1,2],[3,4]] -> 0
    because the value 2 is in the first (idx=0) inner list"""
    for idx, l in enumerate(list_):
        if value in l:
            return idx
    return -1
```

In the following, I am working with a dictionary-based solution. This makes it easier to check if edges already exist.

```
l3 = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5]]
l4 = [[6, 7], [8, 9, 10]]
edges = [[1, 8, 'a'], [4, 9, 'b']]

new_edges = {}
for e in edges:
    # left
    l_idx = idx_group_in_list(e[0], l3)
    r_idx = idx_group_in_list(e[1], l4)
    if (l_idx, r_idx) in new_edges:
        pass    # two edges are squeezed. Maybe add some special stuff here
    new_edges[(l_idx, r_idx)] = e[2]

print(new_edges)
expected_output = {(0, 1): 'a', (1, 1): 'b'}
print(expected_output == new_edges)
```

### Edit:

I've made some very simple performance tests. Most of the code stayed the same I've just changed the way, the lists are generated.

```
num_nodes_per_side = 1000
left = [[i] for i in range(num_nodes_per_side)]
right = [[i] for i in range(num_nodes_per_side, num_nodes_per_side*2)]
edges = [[i, j, 'a'] for i, j in zip(range(num_nodes_per_side), range(num_nodes_per_side, num_nodes_per_side*2))]

# result for num_nodes_per_side = 3
>>> left
[[0], [1], [2]]
>>> right
[[3], [4], [5]]
>>> edges
[[0, 3, 'a'], [1, 4, 'a'], [2, 5, 'a']]
```

This means you have from every left group one edge to a right group.
In the following are my timeit results, based on `num_nodes_per_side`.

- 10:    2.0693999999987778e-05
- 100:   0.0004394410000000404
- 1000:  0.042664883999999986
- 10000: 4.629786907

Comment: Is this the best in terms of performance? Or can we do better....the original graph and the merged graphs need not be lists, I just defined them as lists. Is there any other data structure that would be better suited for this?

Comment: Why do you care about performance? Do you have really huge sets or do you need to calculate them very often? If this is not the case you shouldn't try to optimize your code too much. Graph nodes could also be represented in a ``set``. A set is like a list, but every value is unique. But I don't know if this has any advantage.

Comment: Yes the graphs could be huge

Answer (score 1):

To achieve a better performance, you can use `dict` to [inverted index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverted_index)(make sure node id is unique). which improve the search time complexity from O(n) to O(1), but you need take the cost to rebuild the data structure. Here is a sample code:

```
d3 = {node : idx for idx, l in enumerate(l3) for node in l}
d4 = {node : idx for idx, l in enumerate(l4) for node in l}

for node1, node2, name in edges:
    if node1 in d3 and node2 in d4 or node2 in d3 and node1 in d4:
        print(node1, node2, name)
```

output:

```
1 8 a
4 9 b
```

---

If you want to check duplicate edge like @Uli Sotschok does, it is simliar:

```
new_edges = {}
for node1, node2, name in edges:
    if node1 in d3 and node2 in d4:
        l_idx = d3[node1]
        r_idx = d4[node2]

        if (l_idx, r_idx) not in new_edges:
            new_edges[(l_idx, r_idx)] = name

print(new_edges)
expected_output = {(0, 1): 'a', (1, 1): 'b'}
print(expected_output == new_edges)
```

output:

```
{(0, 1): 'a', (1, 1): 'b'}
True
```